# Stop form from sending and execute a function

Tags: javascript

This is my form:

```
<form id="search_form" method="get" action="" name="search_f">
  <input id="search_field" maxlength="100" name="query" type="text" value="" placeholder="cerca nel negozio">
  <input id="search_button" type="submit" value="" onClick="submit_f()">
</form>
```

This is "submit_f()":

```
function submit_f(){
  var v = document.search_f.query.value;
  var v_arr = v.split("?");
  alert(v_arr.join('\n'));
  var v_arr = v_arr[0].split("/");
  alert(v_arr.join('\n'));
  if((v_arr[0] == "http:" || v_arr[0] == "https:") && v_arr[2] == "store.steampowered.com")
    window.location.href = "/" + v_arr[3] + "/" + v_arr[4];
  else
    window.location.href = "/search/?query=" + v;
  return false;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to redirect the user to different pages based on what he enters:
- If he enters **words** he'll be redirected to **"/search/?query=words"**.
- IF he enters an url (**http://store.steampowered.com/app/202170/?asp=123**) he'll be redirected (in this case) to **"/app/202170"**.

But my code isn't working, any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't returning anything from your event handler function:

```
onClick="submit_f()"
```

should be

```
onClick="return submit_f()"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should give your form a

```
onsubmit="return false"
```

to avoid the default submitting behaviour. Also, your button could be type=button instead of type=submit, but that's not always enough (some browsers will still submit it), the sure way is onsubmit.

Answer (score 1):

remove the `onclick` from your html

```
document.getElementById('search_button').onclick = function(){
    var v = document.search_f.query.value;
    var v_arr = v.split("?");
    alert(v_arr.join('\n'));
    var v_arr = v_arr[0].split("/");
    alert(v_arr.join('\n'));
    if((v_arr[0] == "http:" || v_arr[0] == "https:") && v_arr[2] == "store.steampowered.com")
       window.location.href = "/" + v_arr[3] + "/" + v_arr[4];
    else
       window.location.href = "/search/?query=" + v;
    return false;
}
```